# Hammer JS pressup does not work for touch screen?

Tags: javascript, angular, hammer.js

I am trying to implement a functionality in an **Angular 5** application if you **pressed and hold** the button it will start increasing value 1,2,3,4 ... like that until you **pressed up** to that button.

It is working nice if you **pressed and held** it using a mouse but when I tried with **touch device** sometimes it works, sometimes not.

I debug it and got the problem is that it can't detect pressed up if you pressed and hold for a long time.

Here is my implementation

```html
 <button id="btn-legend-decrease" (press)="mouseOnPressedDe($event)" (pressup)="mouseOnStop($event)">
      <mat-icon aria-label="Decrease scale" color="primary">remove</mat-icon>
    </button>

    <button id="btn-legend-increase"  (press)="mouseOnPressedIn($event)" (pressup)="mouseOnStop($event)">
      <mat-icon aria-label="Increase scale" color="primary">add</mat-icon>
    </button>
```

Any idea how I can implement this kind of feature in Angular?

Thanks

Comment: BTW I solved this problem.
1. Sometimes hammer does not work to listen pressup event.
2. For touch purpose better to use touchstart and touchend event.

Answer (score 0):

`"press"` and `"pressup"` really does not work in most cases when are assigned as handlers in html:

```
(press)="mouseOnPressedDe($event)"
```

I solved this issue by assigning directly to `touchEventManager`. Now it works like a clock:

```
let touchEventManager = new Hammer(this.nativeElement, { inputClass: Hammer.TouchInput });
touchEventManager.on('press', this.onPress.bind(this));
```